# removal of spacing between specific UICollectionViewCells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UICollectionFlowLayout` to establish `minimumLineSpacing` between collectionItems, I am trying to find a way to set the spacing to zero for some cells so there is no spacing, i.e they appear to be 'merged' while leaving others with their spaces intact, is it possible to make alterations in the `cellForItemAt` method for example to achieve this?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customColCell", for: indexPath) as! customColCell

     if indexPath.row == 5 {
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 100 // -- this does not result in an individual change...
     }

     cell.textLabel.text = indexPath.row.description
     return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to make alterations in the cellForItemAt method for example to achieve this

No. What you're asking to do is not how a UICollectionViewFlowLayout behaves by default. You will need to write a collection view layout subclass.